# Send attachment with Sendmail

Tags: php, sendmail

I want to send an attachment with PHPmailer, but when I add the 'addattachment' string, the mail is being send in plain text. This is my code:

```
 $headers .= "AddAttachment('downloads/file.pdf','file.pdf')\n";
 $headers .= "Reply-To: Contoso <noreply@contoso.com>\n";
 $headers .= "From: Contoso <info@contoso.com>\n"; 
 $headers .= "Organization: Contoso \n";
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
 $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
 $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\n" ;

 mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers,$param);
```

So the script is working without the 'AddAttachment' rule. How can I add an attachment succesfully?

Comment: That's not PHPMailer

Comment: @gbestard  You're right, I meant sendmail

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial how to send an attachment.

http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php#attachment

Its not enough to set only the header. You have to add the attachment as base64 encoded tring to your message.

```
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('attachment.zip')));
```

Perhaps its much easier to use a lib with do the work something like PHPMailer or [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org) what i prefer.

```
Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've checked the solution at webcheatsheet.com already, doesn't work for me. The mail is being sent in plain text then.

Comment: Yes because your headers are wrong and its possible that he stops if he find a wrong header.